# Why do Chrome APIs not work in Firefox?

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am developing an extension for Firefox and chrome. I used this code to get cookies in chrome in **ContentScript**.

```
getCookies(domain, name, callback) {
                try{
                    chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function (cookie) {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(cookie ? cookie.value : null);
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch(m)
                {
                    console.log(m);
                }

            },
```

I thought this will work in Firefox as well but this is not working there. I tried to use **browser.cookies.get** but its not working as well. Firefox gives me value if I run this in background script.

Can anybody tell me what is the actual issue here.

Comment: chrome.cookies API can't be used in a content script in Chrome, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). Apparently you're incorrectly loading this script also in the background page declaration in manifest.json.

Comment: @DaveNewton, Firefox is intentionally moving towards making it possible to write extensions exactly the same way it's done in Chrome. I myself tested and `chrome` API indeed works in Firefox (maybe not everything, though...)

Comment: @wOxxOm, It is already working in Google Chrome extension. and when I use the same VueJs code into FireFox, it does not work. that's my issue

Comment: Like I said, it's not working the way you think it does. But if you think you know better than the documentation, good luck :-)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].